# Blue edge type for border of the mesh

Tags: modeling, extrude

When I extrude a border, it still stays indicated as a border in blue, even if two faces are on the same edge. Is it normal ? How to remove this blue?
[image]

color explained in:
Rendering » Freestyle » Parameter Editor » Line Set > edge type

Comment: it looks like sharp edges, to clear sharp select all in Edit mode and press ctrl E > Clear Sharp

Comment: Many thx Moonboot, for this answer, ! I didn't knew it was called "sharp"

Comment: I think it's made to sharp the edge when you use the Edge Split modifier